# Why can I not DENY permissions through module signing?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, signature

In the [documentation for ADD SIGNATURE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-signature-transact-sql), they have the following caveat:

> Module signing should only be used to grant permissions, never to deny or revoke permissions.

My question is: why? Conceptually, I think of signature possibly adding to the user token. If the user linked to the certificate or key that signed the module has a DENY permission associated with it, I'd think that it would come along for the ride. My testing shows that it doesn't, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `DENY` permissions do get applied when used via module signing. If your test indicated that nothing happened, then most likely you were experiencing the wonder of ownership chaining ;-). If a User has an explicit `DENY` for `INSERT` on a Table, but the Stored Procedure does an `INSERT` and has the same authorization as the Table, then the User's permission isn't even checked for what the Stored Procedure does, only that the User can `EXECUTE` the Stored Procedure. In order to test you need to prevent ownership-chaining from interfering, and you do that by making the statement(s) within the Stored Procedure Dynamic SQL (i.e. wrap the statement(s) in `EXEC (N'...');` ). Then you can (and will, as my testing shows) see the effect of `DENY` permissions assigned to the Certificate- / Key- based User.

As to why the recommendation to *not* use Module Signing to restrict access, I would say that:

1. The default state is that permission is already implicitly denied for something, else there is no need for the module signing. There is no purpose to adding restrictions in this manner. If restrictions are needed, they can be added to the User / Login / Role.

   Meaning: module signing exists because there are restrictions that need to be overcome (and impersonation is not a great way of overcoming them), not because the system is wide-open and restrictions are needed.
2. The permissions apparatus is, in itself, conceptually different: regular permissions (where `DENY` does work) deals with *who* can do certain operations (i.e. Users / Logins / Roles), but module signing deals with *what* can do certain operations (i.e. code such as Stored Procedures, Triggers, etc). Generally speaking, if you don't want a module to be able to do a particular operation, just don't code it to do that operation in the first place.

   You can't prevent someone from attempting to execute queries that do operations that they shouldn't do, hence we have implicit and explicit `DENY`s. But you do have control over the code ;-)
3. While probably not a reasoning for Microsoft to have made that statement, I would say that a minor reason to avoid it is simply the confusion caused by situations such as your testing (where it appeared to not even work due to ownership-chaining doing its job).

The only time that I can think of, at the moment, to have a `DENY` in module signing is if module signing is used to allow Dynamic SQL to work, and the Dynamic SQL is structured to allow for something along the lines of the User passing in a Table name to do an operation on and you want to ensure that some tables are considered "off limits", though I am not sure that the `DENY` is even needed in this scenario (could perhaps be a case of it simply being easier to `GRANT` access to a Schema but `DENY` one or two Tables within it).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it's just **has no sense** to `DENY` or `REVOKE` permissions through signing modules.

The idea of signing modules constists of granting the pirmissions to some principal to do only some things, not the whole range of actions that it could be able to do if granted that permissions. So that principal is already lacking that permission, and we are looking for a possibility to grant him that permission, but only within that procedure where we decide what and how it can do.

So by signing a procedure with certificate we garant the executor some permissions it needs, this way it can execute the procedure. But if a principal already has no necessary permission, and we revoke/deny even more permissions, what will we achieve?

Basically, what sense  has a procedure that cannot be executed? And signing it with certificate that will revoke/deny permissions to do smth inside it? Just do not include the actoin that should not be done instead of denying it